# How can I determine the underlying type in a numpy object dtype?

Tags: python, numpy

If I have a custom python class, and use that in a `numpy.ndarray`, my array ends up with dtype 'O' (object), which is fine:

```
import numpy

class Test(object):
    """Dummy class
    """
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

    def __float__(self):
        return float(self.value)


arr = numpy.array([], dtype=Test)
```

This gives me `array([], dtype=object)`, but how can I unwrap the dtype to check that the underlying type is `Test`?

This is easy when there are elements in the array, since I can use `isinstance` on any of the members, but when the array is empty, I am stumped. I hope that the underlying type is stored in the dtype somewhere...

Comment: Such an array contains pointers to objects elsewhere in memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. Arrays aren't meant to be used with non-primitive types (efficiently), and really are no different from a (terribly slow) list. In fact, once you go object, you can put anything you want into the array:

```
array((Test(),[])) #works fine, dtype object. Even explicitly setting dtype will not fail, and be ignored.
```

As you can see - if you do not put a primitive `numpy` can convert to, no type enforcing is done.

Though I would not recommend an array at all, if you can guarantee the array contains a single type, then

```
type(arr[0])
```

is really your only option (which is shape dependent of course).

Comment: But won't the dtype be stored in the internal implementation to cast the values' types when the array is filled?

Comment: @SashaTsukanov it will - `object` type. Since anything can be an object, that means you can put anything in the array, and numpy does not track types for individual elements. All elements have to be of the same type, and the way this is handled is with `object`. This defeats the purpose of storing the type though.

Answer (score 0):

```
type(ar.reshape(-1)[0])
```

Shape independent assuming it's not heterogeneous and it's a view, so doesn't take extra memory.